# Clear textbox without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want my textbox to clear it cache whenever a user save data. I want the dialog in the page clear (reset) all the data without the need to refresh the page.

I already tried to put this code in the javascript

```
     _self.someValueHere("");
```

and also tried to put this code in html.

```
     onfocus="if(this.value=='A new value') this.value='';
```

still won't work.

**Here is a piece of my html code:**

```
        <p>
            <label data-bind="text: key"></label><br/>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: newInfo, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" style="width: 196px" />
            <button data-bind="click: addInfo" >Add</button>
            <br/>
            <select size=5 style="width:200px"
                data-bind="options: infos, value: selectedInfo">
            </select>
            <button data-bind="click: removeInfo">Remove selected</button>
        </p>
```

**Here is my javascript**

```
        _self.newInfo = ko.observable("");
        _self.selectedInfo = ko.observable();
        _self.infos = ko.observableArray();
        _self.addInfo = function() {
            if(_self.newInfo() != "") {
                var validateInput = inputChecker(_self.newInfo(), _self.nfield);
                if(validateInput == "") {
                    var is_unique = true;
                    $.each( _self.infos(), function( key, val ) {
                        if(val == _self.newInfo()) {
                            is_unique = false;
                            _self.newInfo("");
                            console.log("first");
                        }
                    });
                    if(is_unique) {
                        _self.infos.push( _self.newInfo() );
                        _self.newInfo("");
                        console.log("second");
                    } else {
                        alert("Duplicate entry");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert(validateInput);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Nothing to add");
            }
            return false;
            _self.newInfo("");
        };
        _self.removeInfo = function() {
            _self.infos.remove( _self.selectedInfo() );
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute code after a return statement, so the second line here has no effect:

```
return false;
_self.newInfo("");
```

Just swap them:

```
_self.newInfo("");
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the solution. I've figure out that I should execute code to clear the textbox first before I open the dialog box at that page. Thumbs up for good answer!